# What is the meaning of "remove" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in a chapter named "The Browning's version" which was:

I'm still in the lower fifth. I can't specialise until next term - that's to say, if I've got my remove all right.

According to Oxford Dictionaries, "remove" means division in British schools.
But that doesn't fit here. Shouldn't there be "result" instead of "remove"?

Comment: Link to chapter- https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/kehb106.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwib1M3SnN7gAhXCeisKHa4TD38QFjACegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw0M0YO6DOyLhLyWl06Y39yC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an old term in English education for the process of advancing from one class to the next. It's like "passing a grade" in the American system, except (from what I can tell from old fiction) it was something people did more often at odd times of the year, rather than always the end of the year. Limited to private education, though.